# How can I display directory in Ace-Editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, ace-editor

I am making a text editor specifically for python that uses Pyodide to run and display code output. However I am stuck on implementing two things, one being that I want to be able to display all the files in the current directory the file is open in. For clarification, my current code can only open 1 python file at a time at a directory of my choosing. For example if I choose /_static/test_folder/main.py to be displayed, I want to be able to display a list of all the other files in test_folder on the left side of the editor. Such as in the image below:

[image]

Secondly I want to show tabs of said files on the top similar to what vs code does, I believe this can be done without any javascript and just some fancy HTML and CSS however I am not really sure how to approach it. How would I be able to do either? Here is the code I have, its pretty simple but it works pretty good, I just want to add those 2 additional features:

code-editor.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Pyodide in Action</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.4/ace.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.4/ext-static_highlight.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.4/ext-modelist.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/file-saver"></script>
    <script src="pyodide.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="one">
            <pre id="editor" style="width: 1225px;height:500px;"></pre>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="run_code">Mark</button><br>

    <br>

    <textarea rows=10 cols=30 id=output style="margin: 0px; width: 1210px; height: 461px;">Loading and compiling...</textarea><br>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="challenge-editor.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

styles.css:

```css
#editor { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1225px;
    height: 500px;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
.one {
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
}
.two {
    margin-left: 50%;
    height: 500px;
}

#run_code {
    border-radius: 4px; /* Adjust the value to change the roundness of the corners */
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #408ddf;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

challenge-editor.js:

```js
const fileSaver = require('file-saver');

var editor = ace.edit("editor");
var output_pane;
var filePath = '/_static/test_files/main.py';

languagePluginLoader.then(() => {
    // pyodide is now ready to use...
    appendOutput('Python ready.\n');
});

function appendOutput(msg) {
    // used to add program output to the textarea
    output_pane.value = output_pane.value + '\n' + msg;
    output_pane.scrollTop = output_pane.scrollHeight;
}

function configEditor(){
    // configure the ace editor to make it usable
    editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/python");
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.setBehavioursEnabled(true);
    editor.setFontSize(13);
    openCode(filePath);
}

function openCode(filePath) {
    fetch(filePath)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(code => {
        var modelist = ace.require("ace/ext/modelist");
        var modeName = modelist.getModeForPath(filePath).mode;
        console.log(modeName);
        editor.session.setMode(modeName);
        editor.session.setValue(code);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error occurred while opening the code:', error);
      });
  }

async function runCode(code_to_run) {
    // run the code from the editor and display the output in the textarea
    console.logs = [];

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.pyodide.runPython(code_to_run)
        resolve(true)
    }).catch(err => {
        alert("Error: " + err)
    });

    let result = await promise;
    if (result) { 
        appendOutput(console.logs.join('\n')); 
        save_code(code_to_run);
    }
}

function save_code(code) {
    var blob = new Blob([code], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
    window.saveAs(blob, filePath);
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

    output_pane = document.getElementById("output");

    document.getElementById("run_code").addEventListener('click', function () {
        runCode(editor.getValue());
    });

    // Capture the output from Pyodide and add it to an array
    console.stdlog = console.log.bind(console);
    console.logs = [];
    console.log = function(){
        console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
        console.stdlog.apply(console, arguments);
    }
    
    configEditor();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create additional "edit sessions" and change what you're editing using [editor.setSession](https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-api-docs/classes/Ace.Editor.html#setSession), like so (assuming that Ace Editor reference is in `editor`, like in [kitchen sink](https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html)):

```js
var EditSession = ace.require("ace/edit_session").EditSession;
var oldSession = editor.getSession();
// change session:
var newSession = new EditSession("import antigravity", "ace/mode/python");
editor.setSession(newSession);
// change it back later:
setTimeout(function() {
    editor.setSession(oldSession);
}, 5000);
```

The rest is up to you - find yourself a "tree view" library that you like and make it switch to the respective edit session upon clicking the file element.